# Re-use disk with RAID controller

Tags: raid, vmware

I have a HP Microserver Gen8 with two 2 TB disks.
As I am using VMWare ESXi, I could not use HP's built-in RAID controller as it is not recognized by VMWare.
The system is set up and running fine.
Now I got a HP SmartArray P410 controller.
I would like to use this controller now.
I am not able to save all the disks, as I do not have enough room for a full backup at the moment.
Is it save to just connect the disks to the new RAID controller and continue to work with them in the previous configuration?

(In a next step, I could insert two new disks, create a new logical disk drive (RAID 1) and move the VMs from the one logical disk to the other.)

Would this be possible?

Comment: Possible: Probably.   But how important is your data? Do you want to risk it?  And which RAID level do you want to move to? (e.g. if RAID0 you might be able to play with a broken mirror and rebuild quickly. If RAID 5 and large disks that would not be an option).

Comment: I would continue using the current disks as non-RAID disks on that controller.
Then I would connect two new disks and configure them as RAID 1.
I would then install VMWare ESXi on that disks and import the VMs from the non-RAID disks.